# how to change TEMP environment variable of another account (windows 7)?

Tags: environment-variables, admin

I have an issue. There is a user that was previously created to run IIS, as well as other things. The password for said user is unknown. It is not possible to change the password, as it will break various parts of the system.

I need to change the TEMP and TMP environment variables for this account, as it is pointing at C:\Windows\TEMP, which I am not allowing it to have read/write access to for security reasons. So, is it possible to change these environment variables from an admin account in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify them using the registry editor.

Under `HKEY_USERS\<user_sid>` you will find `TEMP` and `TMP` keys, which you can modify to point to the folder you want for that user.